Каким будет правильное прилагательное от слова "электрум"?
В этом и весь вопрос. Я всегда считал, что "монеты из электрума" - электрумовые или электрумные. Образуем прилагательное добавлением суфикса к основе слова. Но мне упорно доказывают, что эти монеты - элекровые. Аргументы у визави такие: "Это норма языка" и "Вместо лингвистических упражнений погугли и посмотри, что к издельям из электрума всегда применялось слово "электровые"".
После того как я провел поиск по нескольким поисковикам я не нашел этого. Но может быть все-таки где-то упоменаются эти "Электровые изделья (монеты)" в качестве исключения?
Обновление: Да, я нашел несколько статей, где упоминалются скифские "электровые сосуды". Но почему "электровые" не ошибка?

Электрум is a word of Latin origin, ultimately from Greek (whence also электрон).
Usually, when borrowing Greek and Latin words, Church Slavonic (and later Russian) authors took the original stem of the word (usually in the genitive or in the accusative, if the stem mutated under declension), and attached Slavic inflectional endings to it.
Most Greek and Latin words have a non-zero ending in the nominative (meaning that they end in -us, -um, -os, -on and similar), that is usually not retained in Russian. This gives us words like символ < συμβολον (symbolon), константа < constans / constantis (gen.) and numerous others. If you look at their Greek and Latin origins, you'll see that they have endings in the nominative that are not there in Russian.
Some words have retained the original endings. For example, the word Христос < Χριστος only has the original Greek ending in the nominative but not in oblique cases (Христа, Христу etc.), but the vast majority of them keep them in all cases: фокус/фокуса, полюс/полюса, пафос/пафоса etc. In all these cases, -ус/-юс/-ос are the original nominative Latin and Greek endings, and the Russian endings are appended on top of them in oblique cases. For people who are familiar with Greek or Latin it looks weird, that's why the ancient authors tended not to do that.
Христос is the only Russian word I can think of that preserves the original ending in the nominative but not in the oblique cases. But when forming adjectives, many such words lose the original ending as well. We have фокальный from фокус, полярный from полюс, патетичный from пафос and so on. Note that these adjectives are paralleled by фокусный, полюсный, пафосный and so on, which might be synonyms or have different shades of meanings, or even completely different meanings altogether.
Электрум is one of such words. It's neuter in the original Latin, and the -um part only exists in the singular nominative: it's electra in the plural nominative, electri in the singular genitive and so on.
It did retain the original ending in Russian, although it didn't have to: спектр < spectrum, ростр < rostrum and many others lost it. But it does (or doesn't) lose this ending in adjectives, apparently, depending on who you ask.

Каким будет правильное прилагательное от слова "электрум"?

This is a niche word, mostly used by historians and archeologists. The "right" way is the one that the "scientific consensus" appoints right. In practice, it means "whatever the loudest guy decides on".
Linguistically, both versions are acceptable, as we see in фокальный/фокусный, полярный/полюсный and many others.
